# sedで改行をスペースに置換出来ない

Tags: sed

```
hoge hoge hoge
hoge hoge
hoge
```

という内容のhoge.txtを　sed 's/\n/ /g'　しても置換されないのですが、その理由を教えていただきたいです
sed 's/ /\n/g' の場合は正常に置換されているのですが...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` は、入力を１行ごとに処理するからです。

多分、今 @doanobu さんがほしいと思っているのは`tr` です。

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

---

もうちょっと補足をすると、 sed の基本的な実行フローは、

1. 一行メモリ(pattern space) に読み込む (改行は含まない)
2. コマンド( `s/\n/ /g` などのこと)たちの実行
3. メモリ(pattern space) の出力(この時再度改行が追加される)

の繰り返しです。なので、何かしらそれ用の操作の指定 ( @argus さんや @mjy さんのように ) をやらないと、改行に対して操作は実行できないです。

Comment: なるほど！　trでうまく動きました　ありがとうございます

Answer (score 4):

参考までに同じ事をする sed スクリプトを載せておきます。

```bash
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x;s/\n/ /g;p;}' hoge.txt
```

これは `hold space` を利用していますが、`pattern space` を使う場合は以下の様になります。

```bash
sed -n ':1;$!{N;b1};${s/\n/ /g;p;}' hoge.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```sh
# GNU の sed ならば
sed -z 's/\n/ /g' hoge.txt
```

GNUの`sed`は`-z`, `--null-data`オプションを指定すると、行の分割を`\n`でなくnull文字で行ないます。